# WIX: Change configuration files even if features set is not changed

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I have a wix installer which installs several web sites. Each website is a feature. There is a custom dialog which allows to enter database connection strings. Each feature contains a component which changes configuration file using the data entered in a dialog. It works fine.

Then I run the same installer and select the option Change. I do not change features set but I change connection strings. Then my changes are not applied to configuration files.

I understand why it happens, no feature change = no component run.

But is there a way to always change config files during change operation even if features list doesn't change?

Comment: I have this exact same problem.  And no one ever responded to you.  I feel like the answer is probably simple.  If you found your own solution, let me know.

Comment: @user922020 Unfortunately not, I don't work on it for years already.